# VHDL signal assigement doesnt work for no apparent reason

Tags: vhdl

I wrote this process in my test bench for a simple 2out/1in reg file entity, here is the relevant part of the test bench:
(note - those signals are std_logic_vector(X downto 0))

```
input : process is
begin
    wait for 30 ns;

    input_adr1  <= "00000";
    input_adr3  <= "00000";
    input_data3 <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
    input_en3   <= '1';
    wait for 10 ns;
    input_en3 <= '0';
    wait for 10 ns;

    input_adr1  <= "00001";
    input_adr3  <= "00001";
    input_data3 <= "00000000000000000000000000000001";
    input_en3   <= '1';
    wait for 10 ns;
    input_en3 <= '0';
    wait for 10 ns;

    input_adr1  <= "00010";
    input_adr3  <= "00010";
    input_data3 <= "00000000000000000000000000000010";
    input_en3   <= '1';
    wait for 10 ns;
    input_en3 <= '0';
    wait for 10 ns;

    wait;
end process input;
```

However, when I go over to ModelSim to check out the waves, the signal `input_data3` never changes - even though I assign it values 0000, 0001, 0002 (hex) in the sequential code. Notice that signals `input_en3`, `input_adr3` both behave properly. Check it:

[image]

```
  drivers input_data3
Drivers for /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(31:0):
   U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(31)
     0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
     U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(31)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(30)
     0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
     U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(30)
   U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(29)
     0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(29)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(28)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(28)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(27)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(27)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(26)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
     U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(26)
   U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(25)
     0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(25)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(24)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
     U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(24)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(23)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(23)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(22)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
     U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(22)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(21)
     0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(21)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(20)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(20)
   U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(19)
     0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
     U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(19)
   U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(18)
     0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
     U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(18)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(17)
     0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(17)
   U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(16)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(16)
   U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(15)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(15)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(14)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
     U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(14)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(13)
     0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
     U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(13)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(12)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
     U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(12)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(11)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(11)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(10)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(10)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(9)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(9)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(8)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(8)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(7)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(7)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(6)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(6)
   U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(5)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(5)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(4)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(4)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(3)
     0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(3)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(2)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
      U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(2)
   U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(1)
      1 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
     U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(1)
    U  : Signal /procesor_tstbnch/input_data3(0)
      0 : Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input
     U  : Element /procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(0)
```

What am I missing? I'm not sure I understand how come this signal assignment doesn't go through.

EDIT: I've also attempted to move all the assignments to input_data3 in another process, it still never changes.

Here are the drivers of input_data3:

Comment: Are the signals shown in the waveform the exact testbench signals you're assigning, or are they the signals inside the UUT?

Comment: You may want to post your question over at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: those are from the test bench
@ Hanno, thanks, ill have the in mind next time :)

Comment: Do you have another assignment to `input_data3` somewhere else that is causing a multiple conflicting drivers issue?

Comment: No - only those 3 (neither of which happens).
The only other time input_data3 appears in my code is in a port map

Comment: ive checkout out if output_data1 will change during time, and it does - as it should. Only input_data3 is "stuck" or something, somehow... :O

Comment: Select `input_data3` in the waveform viewer, find the option to list the signal drivers, post the result.

Comment: This is almost certainly a multiple driver issue.

Comment: I had to edit the question (comment is too long with driver listing).

Comment: There's an apparent reason. Unfortunately your question isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out your driver listing. For bit 1, for example, your process (`Driver /procesor_tstbnch/input`) is driving a `1`. However, the signal is *also* being driven by something called `/procesor_tstbnch/register_file/in_data3(1)`, which is driving a `U`. The overall result is that the bit is undefined (`U`).

What is `register_file/in_data3`?

Comment: register_file : entity work.reg_file
port map (... in_data3 => input_data3, ...);

Comment: So `in_data` is an input/inout to your module, and is driving data (which happens to be undefined) into your module. But you're also driving the same signal *inside* your module, from the process - you can't do this. Or, to be precise, you can, since these are resolved signals, but you shouldn't.